# Getting an error when starting a rails app server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Part of the traceback on terminal says

> There was an error while trying to load the gem 'jbuilder'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Please help

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
...
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
...
```

Comment: please share contents of your Gemfile.

Comment: @tomshy we'd need a little more info. have you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: Seems like the required gem is not installed. Try executing `bundle install` and then try again

Comment: Also, It's best practice to add logs in the question for better understanding. Other users may able to help you better if you add more description of the problem

Comment: I have jbuilder gem in my Gemfile and ran bundle install severally.

Comment: I'm running on kali linux and I read somewhere that the kali environment isn't very 'friendly' to ruby when installed via 'ap-get'. Is it?

Comment: @tomshy I'd recommend using a ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm. I'd recommend rbenv over RVM. that way if you need different versions of ruby for different projects, then you're all set to go!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try 'bundle install' ?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but
try to check config/database.yml
then try: bundle install --without development test
if you not configure development: and test:
or just comment them.

Comment: I think it doesn't have anything to do with database configuration, it's an initial running of a rails app and I also think the traceback would have suggested it

Comment: bundle install check gem dependencies, and db use gem, and this gem some time use libs, that can be not installed.
for example to use PG db, you need install libpq-dev by command apt install libpq-dev or you can get gem error when run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the various ruby versions I had installed on my machine. The solution was, I removed them and reinstalled ruby using rvm.